# Using require() for templating in mod_perl2

Tags: perl, apache2.2, mod-perl2

I have a couple files that are similar and I want them both to `require` a third file in which I can keep the commonalities.  The third file, however, needs to make use of the variables declared in the first two files.  If I understand correctly, I should be able to declare them using `our` in the first two files to be able to modify them in the third.

However, I don't even get that far.  I don't seem to be able to `require` correctly.  It claims it "Can't locate" my relative path, even though it is relative to something in @INC that it lists immediately after.  It even gives that error if I use an absolute path, which I'm not keen on anyway.

The file has the same permissions as its neighbours, and I can access it via the web browser (it doesn't print anything, but if I make it die() it dies properly, so I know Apache is able to access it, at least.)  Nothing funny in the path: it matches `=~ '^[0-9a-z_./]+$'`

It's not a compile error because, in trying to debug this, I commented out everything besides the last line, which is the `1;` that `require()` needs to succeed.

What might I be doing wrong?

Update per ikegami's request:

`eval { require '../test/testform_common_source.pl' };`

or

`eval { require '/home/myappdev/test/testform_common_source.pl' };`

both produce

`Can't locate /home/myappdev/test/testform_common_source.pl in @INC (@INC contains: /home/myappdev/lib /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 . /etc/httpd) at /home/myappdev/test/testform_step_2.pl line 75.`

Update 2 per ikegami's request:

```
-rw-rw-r--   1 chopper chopper 2090 Oct 28 12:34 testform_common_source.pl
-rw-rw-r--   1 chopper chopper 5608 Oct 29 06:51 testform_step_2.pl
```

Comment: Re: "It claims it "Can't locate" my relative path", Please provide the complete error message, the value passed to `require` and the full path to the file being required. Feel free to make substitutions to retain privacy (e.g. change your user id to `userid` or `foo` and your company name to `company` or `bar`, etc).

Comment: @ikegami, I'm not sure how it helps if I make substitutions, but anyway, it's posted above.

Comment: Step 2. What's the output of `ls -l /home/myappdev/test/testform_common_source.pl /home/myappdev/test/testform_step_2.pl`

Comment: @ikegami, As I said in the OP, the file has the same permissions as its neighbours and can be accessed by httpd, but I pasted as you requested.  What are you actually looking for?

Comment: There's no reason for Perl to be giving you that error based on what you said. You could double check for non-printable characters that might have gotten lost in the copy and paste. (Note that I noticed that you either didn't run the command I asked or you chopped off some of the output. Not the right way to inspire confidence in your claims.)

Comment: @ikegami, unprintable characters in my path?  No, all [0-9a-z._/].  And like I said, Perl can read the file all right if I access via web browser (I assume at some level mod_perl is doing an `eval {require...}` on a slurp of my .pl file that way too.)  'K, thanks for checking things, I guess I'm not crazy...

Comment: Yeah, like a trailing space or newline. Registry? it reads the file then does `eval "sub { $file }"`

Comment: All directories in the complete path need to have the x bit, otherwise `testform_common_source.pl` is not accessible, even if it has the r bit.

Comment: @SlavenRezic, they do, I just checked to be sure, but I mean, none of my other scripts would work if they didn't, right?